# PHP How To Get Value from div onclick

Tags: php, html

how i can check if div onclick="test(1)"

```
<div class="range" style="left:150px; background: url(/img.png) -106px 0" onclick="test(1)"><b>about 1:<br>info 1</b></div>
```

i arleady try use `$_GET` but doesnt work

```
if($_GET['test(1)']){
do something doesn't work


 }
```

Comment: Why would calling a JavaScript function suddenly trigger PHP? By the time that JavaScript code has run the PHP is *finished* and no longer executing. The browser must operate independently or use an AJAX call to trigger more PHP activity.

Comment: start by editing your question that contains the `test()` method? and if not, start by creating one. This question's way too unclear and you're trying to fire up a method through a GET which I don't "get".

Comment: so why would you expect your function name to be in your GET superglobal?

Comment: @AdamForbis yea, i found and now full working

Comment: Are you saying your problem is solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can not get `onclick` value like that( `$_GET` ), but you can do something like this in javascript:

```js
if(document.getElementById('myDiv').getAttribute('onclick') == "test(1)"){
console.log("True, your value is " + document.getElementById('myDiv').getAttribute('onclick'));
}else{
console.log("False, your value is " + document.getElementById('myDiv').getAttribute('onclick'));
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="range" style="left:150px; background: url(/img.png) -106px 0" onclick="test(1)"><b>about 1:<br>info 1</b></div>
```

Just add Id to your element and check it with javascript. If you don't want to use id, you can do the same thing using Tag or Class name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("range")[0].getAttribute('onclick');
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute('onclick');
```

And about `$_GET['test(1)']`:

`$_GET` Is used for post and get methods which are used by `<form>` elements:

```
<form method="GET" action="page.php"><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
```